# Filter a specific property out of a JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, jquery, javascript-objects

I have the following `JavaScript` object:

```
Object {article: jQuery.fn.init[11], thesis: jQuery.fn.init[6], chapter: jQuery.fn.init[0], book: jQuery.fn.init[0], proceedings: jQuery.fn.init[0]…}
article: jQuery.fn.init[11]
book: jQuery.fn.init[0]
chapter: jQuery.fn.init[0]
proceedings: jQuery.fn.init[0]
thesis: jQuery.fn.init[6]
translated_title: jQuery.fn.init[1]
__proto__: Object
```

Thes `thesis` property, which is a `jQuery` object, in more details:

```
thesis: jQuery.fn.init[6]
0: div#supervisors.thesis-related.supervisors.thesis-related.dynamic-field-list.ui-sortable
1: div.row.thesis-related
2: div.row.thesis-related
3: select#degree_type.form-control.thesis-related.degree_typeform-control.thesis-related
4: input#university.form-control.thesis-related.universityform-control.thesis-related
5: select#license.form-control.thesis-related.licenseform-control.thesis-related
context: document
length: 6
prevObject: jQuery.fn.init[1]
selector: "*[class~="thesis-related"]"
__proto__: Object[0]
```

I would like to filter the initial object to get all the properties except for the thesis but without using `delete` operator and without changing the object itself.

**Edit**: The problem arises as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26611420/refactor-javascript-code-hide-show-panels-and-form-elements-depending-on-valu), in order not to have `if` statements and filter the object each time with `deposition_type` value.

Comment: So, you want to copy the entire object, except for the `thesis` property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do it without `delete`, it's basically a copy operation for each property:

```
var dest = {};
var name;
for (name in source) {
    if (name !== "thesis" && source.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
        dest[name] = source[name];
    }
}
```

Or if you want to get all ES5 on it:

```
var dest = Object.keys(source).reduce(function(memo, name) {
    if (name !== "thesis") {
        memo[name] = source[name];
    }
    return memo;
}, {});
```

Note that this is a "shallow" copy; if any properties on `source` refer to objects (including arrays), that property on `dest` will also refer to that same object.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply but thanks for the help. Appreciated! :)

Answer (score 0):

To copy an object, use `jQuery.extend`:

```
var secondObject = jQuery.extend({}, firstObject);
delete secondObject.thesis;
firstObject.thesis; // still exists
secondObject.thesis; // does not exists
```

Or recreate an object:

```
var secondObject = {};
for(var i in firstObject) {
    if(i !== 'thesis' && firstObject.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
        secondObject[i] = firstObject[i];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Write a clone method
    cloneObj=function(ele,sExcludeProp){
        var tmp;
        if(ele instanceof Array){
            tmp=[];
            for(var i=0;i
                }
            }
        }else{
            tmp=ele;
        }
        return tmp;
    }